# Delete selected parent node and child nodes - Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, treeview, nodes

I have treeview control with one level of parent and child nodes, each node is having a checkbox for selecting nodes after selection if I click remove button I want to delete child or parent what ever is selected, Im using following code and it returns an error

**Code**

```
    protected void btnRemoveOrganisation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (TreeNode Item in tvwSelectedOrganisations.CheckedNodes)
        {

            if (Item.Parent == null)
            {
                foreach (TreeNode ChildNode in Item.ChildNodes)
                {
                    Item.ChildNodes.Remove(ChildNode);
                }

                tvwSelectedOrganisations.Nodes.Remove(Item);
            }
            else
            {
                Item.Parent.ChildNodes.Remove(Item);
            }

        }

    }
```

**Error**

Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

**Modified code**

```
        protected void btnRemoveOrganisation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TreeNodeCollection SelectedNodes = tvwSelectedOrganisations.CheckedNodes;

            foreach (TreeNode Item in SelectedNodes)
            {

                if (Item.Parent == null)
                {
                    tvwSelectedOrganisations.Nodes.Remove(Item);
                }
                else
                {
                    tvwSelectedOrganisations.FindNode(Item.Parent.ValuePath).ChildNodes.Remove(Item);

                }

                if (SelectedNodes.Count == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

            }

        }
```

**Solution**

```
int SelectedCount = SelectedNodes.Count;

            for (int i = SelectedCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {

                if (tvwSelectedOrganisations.CheckedNodes[i].Parent == null)
                {
                    int j = tvwSelectedOrganisations.CheckedNodes[i].ChildNodes.Count;
                    tvwSelectedOrganisations.Nodes.Remove(tvwSelectedOrganisations.CheckedNodes[i]);
                    i += j;
                }
                else
                {
                    tvwSelectedOrganisations.FindNode(tvwSelectedOrganisations.CheckedNodes[i].Parent.ValuePath).ShowCheckBox = false;
                    tvwSelectedOrganisations.FindNode(tvwSelectedOrganisations.CheckedNodes[i].Parent.ValuePath).ChildNodes.Remove(tvwSelectedOrganisations.CheckedNodes[i]);

                }

            }
```

Comment: Found the solution, issue was due to the generic list being used, I have updtaed the post with correct code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope you are using .Net 3.5 or higher.

```
foreach (TreeNode ChildNode in Item.ChildNodes.ToList())
{
    Item.ChildNodes.Remove(ChildNode);
}
```

**EDIT**

If Item.ChildNodes is not [Enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx). Try below then.

```
for( int i = Item.ChildNodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
{
    Item.ChildNodes.Remove(ChildNode);
}
```

Or

```
while (Item.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
{
    Item.ChildNodes.Remove(ChildNode);
}
```

Comment: im using framework 4, but when I changed the foreach loop, it displayed a build error, "Error 20 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNodeCollection' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNodeCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Just added more options.

Comment: Hi Charith, I have tried the for loop and it worked, updated the post with correct solution. Thanks

Comment: Isn't `.ToList();` part of `System.Linq`? You need to include that if you didn't already, in order for that to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have this line inside the foreach, because you're modifying the collection you're enumerating on:

```
tvwSelectedOrganisations.Nodes.Remove(Item);
```

Instead, build a new list of items to remove, then iterate through that list and remove the items outside of (and after) your existing `foreach`.

Comment: SpikeX and Kalyan, I have tried thisI don't why its removing the same item from my new collection also, I have modified my post to include my new code. Also if I try to delete single node or items in a single node it works, but if select items in multiple nodes it throws same exception

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, it will throw exception. You are not supposed to `delete` or `remove` an item in a collection by looping in the same collection. Instead copy the collection `Item.ChildNodes` to an empty new Collection, try to loop in original collection and remove what items you want in the new collection, after looping outside the scope of loop again re-assign the modified collection to the original.